# Z table Problem in statistic-sample mean

Tags: statistics, random-variables

The problem is stated as the following:

Systolic blood pressure for women between the ages of 18 and 24 is normally distributed with a mean of $114.8$ and s.d. of $13.1$

(a)What is the probability that an individual woman has a blood pressure above 125?

My attempt: $$P(X>125)$$ $$=1-P(X<125)$$ $$=1-P(Z<\frac{125-114.8}{13.1})$$
$$=0.2206$$

(b)Suppose a random sample of n=50 women is selected and the mean blood pressure for sample is computed. What is the probability that the mean blood pressure of the sample will be above 125?

my attempt: $$P(X>125)$$ $$=1-P(X<125)$$ $$=1-P(Z<\frac{125-114.8}{\frac{13.1}{\sqrt50}})$$ $$=1-P(Z<5.50572)$$
and i want to ask for part (b), if i get a result like $Z=5.50572$, do i need to check the Z-table or should i directly write the answer is approximate to $0$?

Comment: By the way, it should not be $Z\color{red}{=}\ldots$, it should be $Z \color{blue}{<}\ldots$.

Comment: oops sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a question for your teacher, not us.  The Z-score tables I have seen stop at about $Z=4$ or so because they present the data to a fixed number of decimal places and the chance of exceeding that is too small to see.  The one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) stops at $4.09$ because it lists five decimals.  Certainly $Z=5.5$ is too small to see on this scale.

If I were the teacher, I would see value in finding an approximate answer.  I like big numbers and I think it is good to see how big they are.  I initially guessed this one would be lottery-sized, tens of millions.  I asked [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-erf(5.50572)) and it is larger than that.  Your probability is about $7\cdot 10^{-15}$.  It is good to see that $5.5\sigma$ just doesn't happen.  If you say it is close to zero, you don't identify how close.

Comment: Another way to state this by using a provided Z-table, is to simply note that if the table lists probabilities to 5 decimal places, then $Pr[Z \ge 5.50572] < 0.00001$.  This allows one to make a quantitative statement about the probability without needing to look beyond the table to make a claim as to the order of magnitude.